# postgresql / pgAdmin - server doesn't listen issue

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am setting up postgresql / pgadmin on my new macbook pro. However, when I register a new server, I get the error:

```
Server doesn't listen
The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports 
could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I browsed this issue and apparently the answer is to edit the `pg_hba.conf` file. However, i need help with:

1) How do I find & open that file?

2) Once I open it, what statements do I need to add to fix the issue?

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The file and its location and syntax is documented in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+[pgadmin]+Is+the+server+running+on+host+%22localhost%22)

Answer (score 1):

It is situated inside the `data` folder.

> Eg: PostgreSQL\9.4\data\pg_hba.conf

There you will find the following place.

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

If you want to access from different IP add a copy of the same line changing the IP.
Its well explained [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

And also I suggest you to check the `postgresql.conf` placed in the same directory for the following line whether its commented on not.

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```